# Is the post_save signal in Django atomic?

Tags: django, django-signals

I really can't find anything solid in the docs. Lets say I'm doing something like this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Item(models.Model):
    total_score = models.IntegerField()

    def set_score(self):
         ...

class Review(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField()

@receiver(post_save, sender=Review)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.item.set_score()
```

What I'm trying to do is call `set_score()` for the item object, whenever a review object is saved. Is this atomic? I definitely want the whole thing to be atomic, as a situation where a review is saved, but the item's total score is not updated is a recipe for bugs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there's nothing special about signals with regard to database transactions (the only kind of atomicity handled by Django). It's up to you to ensure that the relevant commands are always part of the same database transaction.

One approach would be to simply rely on the calling code to do this by using [`ATOMIC_REQUESTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-ATOMIC_REQUESTS), using transactions in your views, etc.

Or, since `post_save` signals are sent as part of `Model.save()`, you could simply override `Review.save()` and make it use a transaction.

```
class Review(models.Model):
    ...

    @transaction.atomic()
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```